# WCF SocketException

Tags: c#, wcf, socketexception

I'm developing a WCF application in VS2010. When I use the in-IDE debugger to run the host application and the client, everything works as intended.

However, when I run the two executables manually (going to the /bin/Debug/ folders), I get the following exception from the client:

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8732

The odd thing is, in the app.config file I'm specifying to use port 5000, not 8732.

What's wrong? Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Here is the app.config for the host application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFServiceLibrary.SavalotServiceObject">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFServiceLibrary.ISavalotService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:5000/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFServiceLibrary/SavalotServiceObject/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: what happens when you press ctrl + F5 and run it without debugging

Comment: then your problem is that your config file has debug specific settings in it.

Comment: deltree I added the app.config to my post above, what do I need to change? Thanks

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what tags are for.

Comment: @Motig visual studio creates a debug & a release config file below your config file http://www.hanselman.com/blog/content/binary/Windows-Live-Writer/1867b7aecfc3_11C1/ConsoleApplication1%20-%20Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%20(122)_2.png

Comment: @deltree Negative, I only have app.config. No node to expand like in your picture.

Comment: Try rebuild solution, instead of build solution.  Occasonally my config files refuse to get overwritten.  If that doesn't work, try deleting everything in the /bin folder and rebuild solution again.  Let me know if that gets it.

Comment: @deltree Nope, still only one app.config.

Comment: @Motig I meant, see if that gets it working

Comment: Ah okay. Nope, it still seems to be trying to contact the host on 8732, I really can't see why.

Comment: is this a multiple project solution?  Are you changing the correct config?  If you're testing, your test project needs the app config with the correct endpoint, if you're hosting hte project, the wcf service project needs the web.config with the correct endpoint.

Comment: @deltree It's a multiple project solution, yes. That has fixed it, I guess I'm a noob with WCF so sorry to have wasted your time. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POSTED SO USERS DON'T HAVE TO GO THROUGH 13 COMMENTS

In this case, the problem was that the user was running a multi-project Solution.  In that case, whichever project is being run is the project whose config file matters.

If you're **running** the WcfService, you'll need the project with the service in it to have its `web.config` file configured to use the right ports.

If you're **testing** the WcfService, you'll need the test project to have its `app.config` file configured to use the right ports.

This is a common error those new to webservices make and is nothing to be ashamed of.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using something like [WireShark](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cts=1331759519811&ved=0CD8QjBAwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wireshark.org%2Fdownload.html&ei=ZgphT532PMXlggev9viGCQ&usg=AFQjCNEZ0wPfsDui_crW6GRocCdpH9_jtg&sig2=eTAz5oSGJfe0q99MWdVJRQ)?  Running it at both endpoint is a good way to troubleshoot socket woes.