# Why am I getting an exception (TCP error code 10061) when attempting to communicate between 2 applications using WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ipc

I am trying to use WCF to setup IPC between 2 running windows applications.
 I want to start out by saying that I know there are other (better?) ways to implement
 this solution. But, due to some pre-existing design considerations/constraints, I'm bound to using:
 - netTcpBinding 
 - DuplexChannelFactory<> to support bidirectional communication

All the applications, services, etc reside on the same machine as we will be
 installing everything on a single dedicated piece hardware running MS Windows.

So the schematic kind of looks like this
 WPFApp1
 (Contains ReportingFacilityInterface definition)
 Returns notifications as separate callbacks to WPFApp2
 ^ 
 |
 |
 V 
 ReportingFacilityInterfaceProxy
 ^ 
 |
 |
 V 
 WPFApp2 (needs to call exposed methods on WPF1 ReportingFacilityInterface object)

I've created my WCF "service" class and contracts.
 I'm using a proxy dll to facilitate the communication.

Here's the sequence of events:

---

1)WPFApp1 starts up and instantiates an instance of the exposed service class

```
ReportingFacilityInterface = new ReportingFacility.ReportingFacilityInterface();
```

This starts up fine.

2) WPFApp2 startsup and initializes instance of proxy object

```
reportingFacilityProxy = new ReportingFacilityInterfaceProxy.ReportingFacilityProxy();
```

This instantiates the proxy object, which results in this getting called:

```
reportingFacilityInterface = DuplexChannelFactory<IReportingFacilityInterface>.CreateChannel(objContext, "RPIEndPointConfiguration");
```

This seems to run and return successfuly.

3) WPFApp2 calls a on the object (through the proxy)

```
 reportingFacilityInterface.Initialize(configuration);
```

I get an exception with the following detail:

Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:8732/ReportingFacility. 
 The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:02.1931255. 
 TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8732

I examined my current port usage using the CurrPorts application and noticed that port #8732 does is not in the list of currently active/used ports on my machine.

Since I'm pretty green @ the world of WCF, I'm kind of stumped here.
 As I mentioned above, all these are running on the same (dedicated) piece of Windows 7 hardware, so permissions/roles should not be an issue.
 I think I'm pretty close here, but am just missing something.

Thanks,
 JohnB

Comment: seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710351/wcf-socketexception

Answer (score 0):

I'd:

1. Verify your server config to be sure about service endpoint address
2. Run the Service Trace Viewer Tool ([SvcTraceViewer.exe](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx&ei=AsdpUeKJNMi84ASXqIH4AQ&usg=AFQjCNHT5aIcNhLK82vtA4o40IllzeVfTw&sig2=J8S9kJd2DXRDuMtSAaxMcg&bvm=bv.45175338,d.bGE))
3. Add some basicHttpBinding endpoint to be sure you can access it from your browser

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue by going to services and start Net.tcp listener adapter.

Also, you can find more solutions here 
http://blogs.ajithbhat.com/2010/06/tcp-error-code-10061-no-connection.html